# Not able to launch IE8 browser using Selenium Webdriver 3.0.1 using Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8, automated-tests

Code written in eclipse is as follow :

```
  System.setProperty("WebDriver.ie.driver","E:/Selenium/Webdriver/Softwares/IEdriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.get("http://facebook.com");
```

But almost similar code is working fine for Firefox and Chrome browsers.

Comment: Do you see that the 'W' is capital instead of lower-case for your property?  Did you also add the folder containing your driver to the PATH environment variable?  Where did you get IEdriver.exe because Selenium's websites are showing IEDriverServer.exe?

Answer (score 2):

change code as below and try. And please share the error details if it occurs again.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E:/Selenium/Webdriver/Softwares/IEdriver.exe");
```